# Defering drop table after exchange partition

Tags: oracle, alter-table, partition

I have two tables:

`ld_tbl` - a partitioned table.

`tgt_tabl` - a non partitioned table.

In my program I'm executing

```
alter table ld_tbl exchange partition prt with table tgt_table;
```

and after the exchange has finished I'm executing a drop to the `ld_tbl`.

The problem is that if someone has fired a query through the `tgt_tabl` it throws exception:

> ORA-00813: object no longer exists

Even I drop only the `ld_tbl` and didn't touch the `tgt_tabl`. After several tests, I'm sure that it's the drop which causes the exception. According to this information: [Object no longer exists](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9509565700346771185), the solution is to defer the drop.

My question is: how much time is needed between the drop and the exchange? How can I know that operation like drop will not hurt the other table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "how much time need to be between the drop and the exchange?"

The pertinent question is, why is anybody running queries on the TGT_TABL. If I understand your situation correctly that is a transient table, used for loading data through Partition Exchange. So no business user ought to be querying it (they should wait until the data goes live in the partitioned table).

If the queries are coming from non-business users (DBAs, support staff) my suggestion would be to just continue as you do now, and send an email to those people explaining why they may occasionally get `ORA-00813` errors.

If the queries are coming from business users then it's more difficult. There is no point in deferring the drop, because somebody could be running a query *whenever* you schedule it. You need to track down the users who are running these queries, discover why they are doing it and figure out whether there's some other way of satisfying the need.

But I don't thinks there's s technical fix you could apply. By using partition exchange you are already minimizing the window in which this error can occur.

Comment: APC, thanks for answer. I will try to explain. In standart exchange partition statement, the goal is to move all data from the table with no partitions to the table with the partitions. In my case it's different. I don't have a real partition table that the data need to be in it. I just want to switch data from load table to the target. So the best way is to create the load table as with 1 partition - match for all rows, and exchange this all-rows partition with the target table. so after the exchange finish i don't need the load table. that's why i want to drop it.

Comment: About the question itself - If I get it right, because of the exchange statement, those tables have common relation. So when you drop one of them it can cause exception for access to the second. Maybe I wrong but i think that it's not about the time that user query the table. The user query only raise the excpetion. But why drop of 1 table cause an exception with the other one? because of the exchange... So I think that I will move it forward...